# Regular Expression in java- code error

Tags: java, regex

I wrote a regEx program in java. I think that is true but The result is different. please help me to fix that.

my code:

```
String text    ="My wife back me up over my decision to quit my job";

String patternString = "[/w/s]*back(\\s\\w+\\s)*up[/w/s]*.";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

boolean matches = matcher.matches();

System.out.println("matches = " + matches);
```

output:
        matches = false

I'm new in java programming. I want to write a program with regEx to test match of "back up" in the input sentence.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: What is expected output and what you getting?

Comment: Try using `\\w\\s` instead of `/w/s`.

Comment: I think my regEx is true but the output is false. i want to right a program for my previous question. please help me. my previous question link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15563185/extract-prepositional-and-phrasal-verbs-with-regular-expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you pattern should be like this:

```
String patternString = "[\\w\\s]*back(\\s\\w+\\s)*up[\\w\\s]*.";
```

Comment: Jho, thanks for your answer. Can you answer my question in my previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15563185/extract-prepositional-and-phrasal-verbs-with-regular-expression

Answer (score 1):

You are using forward slashes instead of backslashes:

```
String patternString = "[/w/s]*back(\\s\\w+\\s)*up[/w/s]*.";
                         ^ ^                       ^ ^
```

The two are not interchangeable (and don't forget that backslashes need to be doubled up).